# Conditionally execute Jenkins pipeline stage on tagged commits

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In our Jenkins pipeline, we are currently publishing build artifacts when commits are made to specific branches.

The `Jenkinsfile` currently has something like this:

```
stage("Publish to Docker Registry") {
    when { anyOf { branch "release"; branch "prerelease" } }
    ...
}
```

We would like to change this to executing on any tagged commit, but I cannot find anything about using tags as a trigger in the documentation:

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when

Is this possible?

We are using git.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to look from the jenkins side. You need to look for information about webhook using git comments.

For example in my company we have a webhook in gitlab that push every comment to jenkins but jenkins only build the ones that say "jenkins please build"
 [image]

And then you need to configure in jenkins like a build trigger
[image]